# xcode GoogleGobileAds.h file not fount

Tags: xcode

I am using Xcode version 11.4
my code run correctly and I made an apk and all was fine. but using xcode i am getting thi error:

GoogleMobileAds.h file not found.

i inserted the GoogleMobileAdsSdk for ios but problem not solved and nothing worked

any suggestions?

Comment: Did you figure this out? I have same issue.